# Access variable from main function

Tags: c++

I want to access a value in loadconfig function but always error:

> request for member ‘a’ in ‘LoadConfig’, which is of non-class type ‘int()’

```
string trainData, testData, simName;
int b, i;

int LoadConfig()
{
    int a;
    ifstream fin("kddcup.txt"); 

    while(getline(fin,trainData))
    {
        // do whatever to the string "line"
        //  cout << i + 1 << "  "<< trainData << endl;

        char *pcg = strdup(trainData.c_str());
        //pcg=(char *)malloc(42);
        trainData = strtok(pcg,",");
        i=1;
        while (pcg != NULL)
        {
            int tint=atoi(pcg);
            int tmp[43];

            //printf ("%s",pcg);

            tmp[i]=tint;

            pcg = strtok (NULL, ",");
            //printf("value = %d \n",tmp[i]);
            if (i==5)
            {
              a = tmp[i];   
              printf("value a= %d \n",a); //access this a
            }
            else if(i==6)
            {
              b=tmp[i]; 
              //printf("nilai b = %d \n",b);
            }

            i++;
        }//while pcg
    }

    //   getline(fin, trainData);
}

int main() 
{
  int r;
  LoadConfig();
  // I WANT access from here
  LoadConfig.a = new LoadConfig();
  printf("output fungsi main = %d ",r);
}
```

Comment: Sure this is C++, but I don't see the C++11 part. Also, you probably don't want access.

Comment: It seems you need a LoadConfig as a Class.But in Your case it's not a class and you can not access a member called 'a' in your main program which is present in a function.

Comment: Your code is fairly hard to read. Feel free to remove excess spaces and abandoned code from your post. And please try to format nicely like NPE's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is by *returning* `a` from the function:

```
int LoadConfig()
{
    int a;
    ...
    return a;
}

int main() 
{   int r;  
    r = LoadConfig();
    printf("output fungsi main = %d ",r);   
}
```

If you want to return more than a single `int`, then one way would be to encapsulate all the things that you want to return into a `class` or a `struct`, and return that.

Comment: there less one thing.i already use that the output is not complete.only one value that can parsing.